# How to write in a RichTextBox on a Form from a function in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `RichTextBox` member named `richTextBox1` in my class `Form1`. I'm trying to append text to the text box from a method:

```
public partial class Form1:Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   public static void info(string str)
   {
       Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
       fm1.richTextBox1.AppendText(str);
   }
   // ...
}
```

I have a set up an event handler for a button's `Click` event in the same class, which calls the `info` method above:

```
info("Hello World");
```

When clicking on the button, I expected to see the text in the `richTextBox1`. However, it's not working and I can't find the problem.

Please explain what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of your form every time the button is clicked.
What you want to do is append the text to the text box existing in the same instance as the button:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void info(string str)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText(str);
    }
}
```

**Notice** that the `static` keyword isn't there anymore.

Comment: But now it tells me that an object reference for the non-static field. method, or property is required. Im calling this function alot of times, so I seriously have to create a new object of my class for this call everytime?

Comment: @missjohanna Need more information than that. Where does it say that? Show the entire surrounding code.

Comment: @missjohanna Where are you calling `info()` from?

Comment: In the errorlog of Visual Studio. Im calling it from different other functions but just in some it makes trouble: public static int work(string path, string path_c)
        {
            int erg = 0;

            info("\n\n***********************************************************************"); }

Comment: @missjohanna Notice that you cannot call instance methods (e.g. the `info` method in my example - notice the lack of `static`?) from static methods.

Comment: Well. That fixed my issue. I was always on the wrong point thinking that I just can use static functions in a class.